# Post value radio button with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two fields in my database 'administrator' and 'moderator' type radio button and I would like:

- **Save the value 1 when I chose the administrator and the value 0 for
  the moderator**
- **and when I chose the moderator I would like to save the value 1 and
  the value 0 for the adminitrator**

I try with this code but it doesn't work.

my view :

```
<label class="mt-checkbox">
  <input type="radio" id="administrator" name="radio" value="administrator"> Administrator
</label>
<label class="mt-checkbox">
  <input type="radio" id="moderator" name="radio" value="moderator"> Moderator
</label>
```

My Controller :

```
public function add_profil(Request $request)
    {

            $profil = new Profil();

            if($request->adminitrator == 'checked'){

                $profil->adminitrator = 1;  
                $profil->moderator = 0;  

            } 
            elseif ($request->moderator == 'checked')   {

                $profil->moderator = 1;  
                $profil->adminitrator = 0; 
            }   

            $profil->save();


    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem here? isn't your code works fine? whats the results of this action in your controller? please tell what you want to achieve and what cant you do?

Comment: Is this in a form right? First of all you miswrite administrator in your solution. Then i think you need to check for `$request->radio` value

Answer (score 1):

Your request has `<input name='radio'>` so you'll want to find the request with that, like so:

```
    public function add_profil(Request $request)
    {

            $profil = new Profil();

            if($request->radio == 'adminitrator'){

                $profil->adminitrator = 1;  
                $profil->moderator = 0;  

            } 
            elseif ($request->radio == 'moderator')   {

                $profil->moderator = 1;  
                $profil->adminitrator = 0; 
            }   

            $profil->save();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the request has been sent, you get inputs with their names. so your radio buttons have the name 'radio'. So you should check the request with that input name, not the value of the input.

I recommend you fetch the requests with request->all() method and set it to a variable $request. This way you can treat request like an array and access the request values with the key that is same as the name of the input.

So you can do it this way:
first, in your controller, you must check what is the request value with the name of radio and then if it has the value of administrator you put administrator value of one and then the moderator value of 0. And on the other side in else statement you should do it otherwise like this code below:

```
public function add_profil(Request $request)
    {

            $request = request->all();
            $profil = new Profil();


        if($request['radio'] == 'administrator'){

            $profil->adminitrator = 1;  
            $profil->moderator = 0;  

        } 
        elseif ($request['radio'] == 'moderator')   {

            $profil->moderator = 1;  
            $profil->adminitrator = 0; 
        }   

        $profil->save();


}
```

Note that you type the administrator wrong in your if statement. you misstype 's'.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting wrong name in laravel, change form to this:

```
public function add_profil(Request $request)
    {

            $profil = new Profil();

            if($request->administrator == 'checked'){

                $profil->adminitrator = 1;  
                $profil->moderator = 0;  

            } 
            elseif ($request->moderator == 'checked')   {

                $profil->moderator = 1;  
                $profil->adminitrator = 0; 
            }   

            $profil->save();


    }

    <label class="mt-checkbox">
        <input type="radio" id="administrator" name="administrator" value="checked"> Administrator
    </label>
    <label class="mt-checkbox">
        <input type="radio" id="moderator" name="moderator" value="checked"> Moderator
    </label>
```

Comment: No, the problem is that he's checking whether or not the request's value is checked. The value is administrator or moderator.

Comment: oops, yes i missed!